# Building a plugin that doesn't break when deactivated

Tags: plugins

I wrote a WordPress plugin that creates an admin page for deciding what posts go in a feature slider on the front page. Everything works fine and I'm simply calling to the function inside the plugin with

```
    <?php uwffs_display(); ?>
```

in the home.php file.

The issue is that if I were to deactivate the plugin, the home page breaks at the point the

```
    <?php uwffs_display(); ?>
```

function call occurs and stops rendering the rest of the page.

What is a more graceful way I can call this plugin's function so that, if deactivated, it will load the rest of the page?

One thought is I could write it as:

```
    <?php if(function_exists('uwffs_display'))
    {
    uwffs_display();
    }
    ?>
```

Is that the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other option would be to use any hooks available in the Theme, which would allow your Plugin to inject the slider at a filter or action hook. If the Plugin is deactivated, its `add_action()` or `add_filter()` call is never run, nothing attempts to be added to the template, and, voila: no breakage.

But, barring that (and since Themes that offer such custom hooks are still in the minority), `function_exists()` wrapper is the way to go. So +1 to @rmlumley.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.
Checking for the existence of the function in the way that you just posted is the proper way of doing this.